# nc getting stuck unexpectedly

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, nc

I expected this:

```
nc -l localhost 7000 </dev/null &
nc localhost 7000 </etc/profile
```

and this

```
nc -l localhost 7000 </etc/profile &
nc localhost 7000 </dev/null
```

to finish after printing my `/etc/profile`
but both command groups end up getting stuck (both processes in the first case; in the second case, the server finishes but the client does not).

Why don't the commands finish?

Is this a bug in my `nc`/Linux (4.15)? I tried it on MacOS and Cygwin and only the Linux commands aren't finishing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using netcat and not gnu-netcat; I'm not sure what version you're using, but if it's gnu-netcat the options might be different.

I have a `-q` option:

> `-q seconds` after EOF is detected, wait the specified number of seconds then quit

So, if I do:

```
$ nc -l localhost -p 7000 -q 0 < /etc/passwd
```

Followed by:

```
$ nc localhost 7000
```

Then I get the content of `/etc/passwd` on the second terminal, and both instances of `nc` terminate.